# Knight's tour code

Tags: java, recursion, time-limit-exceeded, chess, backtracking

Another one for some late night snack. - Knight's tour!
Please provide your suggestions/flaws/optimization to this knight's tour backtracking code..

```
package com.komal.backtracking;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class KnightsTour {
    static int size = 6;
    static int[][] chessBoard = new int[size][size];
    static int move;
    static int noOfBacktrackCalls;

    public boolean tourBackTrackRoutine(int row, int col) {
        boolean flag = false;
        noOfBacktrackCalls++;
        if (!isMoveSafe(row, col)) {
            return false;
        }
        move++;
        chessBoard[row][col] = move;

        if (move == size * size) {
            return true;
        }

        flag = true;


        int counter = 0;

        for (int i[] : possibleMoves) {
            counter++;
            int newX = row + i[0];
            int newY = col + i[1];
            if (flag = tourBackTrackRoutine(newX, newY)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                if (counter == possibleMoves.length) {
                    move--;
                    chessBoard[row][col] = 0;
                    return flag;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;

    }

    public boolean isMoveSafe(int row, int col) {

        if (row < 0 || col < 0 || !(row < size) || !(col < size)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (row == size || col == size) {
            return false;
        }
        if (chessBoard[row][col] > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    int[][] possibleMoves = { { 2, 1 }, { 2, -1 }, { -2, 1 }, { -2, -1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 1, -2 }, { -1, 2 }, { -1, -2 } };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Solving...");
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        if (new KnightsTour().tourBackTrackRoutine(0, 0)) {
            System.out.println("Solved!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot be solved!!");
        }
        long timeTaken = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        System.out.println("\nCompleted in :" + timeTaken + " milli sec");
        System.out.println("\nTook " + noOfBacktrackCalls + " backtrack calls for completion!");
        for (int[] i : chessBoard) {
            System.out.print("\n{");
            for (int i1 : i) {
                System.out.print(i1 + ",\t");
            }
            System.out.print("}");
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Solving...
Solved!!

Completed in :382 milli sec

Took 20092518 backtrack calls for completion!

{1, 12, 21, 28, 7,  10, }
{22,29, 8,  11, 20, 27, }
{13,2,  23, 4,  9,  6,  }
{30,35, 32, 17, 26, 19, }
{33,14, 3,  24, 5,  16, }
{36,31, 34, 15, 18, 25, }
```

Comment: 8x8 takes for ever to complete though! Waited for like 15 mins, no luck!

Answer (score 5):

> ```
>     static int size = 6;
> ```

This should be `final`, as you don't change it.

> ```
>         boolean flag = false;
>         noOfBacktrackCalls++;
>         if (!isMoveSafe(row, col)) {
>             return false;
>         }
>         move++;
>         chessBoard[row][col] = move;
>
>         if (move == size * size) {
>             return true;
>         }
>
>         flag = true;
> ```

You initialize `flag` and then set it to something else without ever using it.  Why bother?  You could just say

```
        noOfBacktrackCalls++;
        if (!isMoveSafe(row, col)) {
            return false;
        }
        move++;
        chessBoard[row][col] = move;

        if (move == size * size) {
            return true;
        }

        boolean solved = true;
```

I renamed it to `solved` after I figured out what it was.  The name `flag` didn't help me much with understanding what it did.

And the truth is that you don't need it.  I'd simplify down to

```
        noOfBacktrackCalls++;
        move++;
        chessBoard[row][col] = move;

        if (move == size * size) {
            return true;
        }
```

Note that other code will have to change to make this work.

> ```
>         int counter = 0;
>
>         for (int i[] : possibleMoves) {
>             counter++;
>             int newX = row + i[0];
>             int newY = col + i[1];
>             if (flag = tourBackTrackRoutine(newX, newY)) {
>                 return true;
>             } else {
>                 if (counter == possibleMoves.length) {
>                     move--;
>                     chessBoard[row][col] = 0;
>                     return flag;
>                 } else {
>                     continue;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         return flag;
> ```

First, that `continue` doesn't do anything.  You're already at the end of the loop.  You can just let it finish.  And without the `continue`, you don't need the `else` block.

As I said earlier, you don't actually need `flag`.  You never set it to `true` except initially.  The first time that you `return flag`, it will always be `false`.  You just set it to `false` before the `else` block.  Otherwise the `else` wouldn't run.  The second `return` will only be reached if there are no possible moves or if `flag` is false.  If you set `flag` to true in the loop, you always `return` immediately.  And you know that `possibleMoves` is not empty, as you set it.

I'd write this block

```
        for (int i[] : possibleMoves) {
            int newX = row + i[0];
            int newY = col + i[1];
            if (isMoveSafe(newX, newY) && tourBackTrackRoutine(newX, newY)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        move--;
        chessBoard[row][col] = 0;

        return false;
```

No `flag` needed.

I also removed `counter`.  You were only using it to give a different behavior on the last iteration of the loop.  But putting the code outside the loop accomplishes the same thing.

I moved the `isMoveSafe` to here so that it runs before the recursive call.

#### Performance

The performance is determined by the algorithm here.  These changes tweak performance a bit, but the algorithm is still the problem.  You may want to check out some previous questions for more ideas.  E.g.

- [Knight's Tour with Heuristics](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/75585/71574)
- [Optimizing this Knight's Tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79995/71574)